# What is equivalent of "分润"?

Tags: translation

In many trading system I can offen find a concept call "分润".
Is that a **word** in english equivalent to "分润" ?

Comment: it means dividend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of.

The the generic 分润 just means "**profit-sharing**", which is also an easily understood, and similarly generic, English term. Alternatively, "**a cut of the profit**" would also be widely understood, but obviously that's not a single word.

You might also be able to use the English term ["**fee-splitting**"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fee-splitting), if you're talking about sharing fees with a referrer for referring a client (typically, doctors or lawyers). In situations of a illegal connotation, the term ["**rake-off**"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rake-off) could be used. Similarly, the term ["**kickback**"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kickbacks) could be used, but illegality/coercion tends to be implied with that as well.

If you insist on a single word, the generic profit sharing meaning has a word borrowed from French: [**tantième**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tanti%C3%A8me). I doubt it's a term with much currency in real life, however.